# PHP cookie making problums

Tags: php, html

I need this select to place its result in the cookie.
so i can all on it later after the other selects are entered (other pages) I keep getting a error with it.

this project to a roll call system that will users can log into
this first select gets there name the next one on another page gets if they are here late not there or here the third one gets the if they left early or came in late what time they did so

Notice: Undefined index: Names in C:\xampp\htdocs\RollCallNames.php on line 34

Notice: Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' in C:\xampp\htdocs\RollCallNames.php on line 36
Notice: Undefined variable: cookie in C:\xampp\htdocs\RollCallNames.php on line 37
Cookies are disabled.
Notice: Undefined variable: Enable in C:\xampp\htdocs\RollCallNames.php on line 43

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Earthdawn RPG RollCAll</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <img src="EDBAN.jpg" width="1025" height="430" alt="" />
    <p>
      </br>
    </p>
    <select name="Names" id="Name">
      <option value="a">Cc3768</option>
      <option value="b">Rraun</option>
      <option value="c">Angelos O.</option>
      <option value="d">Chris D.</option>
      <option value="e">Kariem l.</option>
      <option value="f">Dan f.</option>
      <option value="g">Michael W.</option>
      <option value="h">Dougansf</option>
      <option value="i">Sterling B.</option>
      <option value="j">Talmis</option>
      <option value="k">Diajkota</option>
      <option value="l">Caleb H.</option>
      <option value="m">Phantom</option>
      <option value="n">Garalith</option>
      <option value="o">RainDan</option>
      <option value="p">Woopd..</option>
    </select>
   <?php
  $name=$ _POST[ 'Names'];
  setcookie( "test_cookie", "test", time() + 3600, '/');
  $Name=v alue;
  if(count($cookie)>0)
    {
      $Enabled = 2; 
    } 
  else
    {
      echo "Cookies are disabled."; 
      $Enabled = 1; 
    } 
if ($Enable == 2) 
  { 
  if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cook])) 
    { 
      //removes the cookie 
      setcookie($cook, "", time() - 3600);
      //adds the cookie 
      setcookie($Cook, $Name, time() + (3600), "/");
    } 
  else 
    { //add's the cookie setcookie($Cook, $Name, time() + (3600), "/"); 
  }
}
?>

  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry! what do you mean? What is the issue? :)

Comment: you mean `!isset($_COOKIE[$Name])` ??  and there's no reason to "remove the cookie"... you just determined that the cookie doesn't exist + setting a new value will overwrite any existing value

Comment: Maybe what's not the issue! The select isn't in a form, there are typos, like $ _POST (notice the whitespace), and v alue. Also you are trying to put the POST value into a variable before the form (you still dont have a form) was sent, use `if(isset($_POST['Names']))` for this problem.